# ReactJS parameter pass a token to a Route using react-router-dom 6.4

Tags: reactjs

I want to send the variable `userObject` into a `const Layout`. The userObject is a jwt decoded Google token.

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import useToken from './useToken';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"

import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import NoPage from "./pages/NoPage";


function App() {

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if(!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  }
  else{
    // User object from token
    var userObject = jwt_decode(token)
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{userObject.name}</h1>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route index element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**pages/Login.js**

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
    {/* Header */}
    <header>
      {/* Header left */}
      <div className="header_left"></div>
      {/* Header center */}
      <div className="header_center">
        Center
      </div>
      {/* Header right */}
      <div className="header_right">
        {userObject.name}
      </div>
    </header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
};

export default Layout;
```

**useToken.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return userToken?.token
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', userToken.token);
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Login.css';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"

const google = window.google;

export default function Login({ setToken }) {

  // Handle response from Google login
  async function handleCallbackResponse(response){
    // console.log("Google token: " + response.credential)
    // var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential)
    // var userEmail = userObject.email;
    // console.log("userEmail=" + userEmail)
    document.getElementById("sign_in_form_google").hidden = true;

    // Call login on backend async
    const backendToken = await loginBackend(response.credential)
    if(!(backendToken)){
      document.getElementById("feedback_div").hidden = false;
    }
    else{
      // console.log("Backend token: " + backendToken)
      setToken(backendToken);
    }
  }

  // Login to backend
  async function loginBackend(credentials){
    // console.log("Login.js :: loginBackend():: Logging in with " + credentials)
    var backendToken = fetch('https://localhost:5000/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials
        }
      }).then(data => data.json())
    // console.log("Login.js :: loginBackend() :: Response is " + backendToken)
    return backendToken
  }

  // Google Login 
  useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "xxx-yyy.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("sign_in_button_google_inner"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
    )

    google.accounts.id.prompt();

  }, []);

  return(
    <div className="login_body_bg">
      <div className="login_wrapper">
          {/* User login header */}
          <div className='login_header'>
            <div className='login_header_left'>
              <p>My website</p>
            </div>
            <div className='login_header_right'>
              <img src="gfx/login/logo_100x49.png" alt="Logo" />
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* User login main */}
          <div className='login_main'>
            <h1>Please Log In</h1>

            {/* Feedback */}
            <div id="feedback_div" className="error_medium" style={{display: "none"}}><p className="feedback_p">Login failed</p></div>

            {/* Login form */ }
            <div id="sign_in_form_google">
              <p>Use Google to login below.</p>
              <div id="sign_in_button_google_wrapper">
                <div id="sign_in_button_google_inner"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* User login footer */}
          <div className="login_footer">
            <p>&copy; 2022 Me</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
pass it as a prop as usual

```js
<Route path="/" element={<Layout userObject={userObject} />}>
```

**Option 2** Why not include the responsibility of jwk_decode in useToken or rename it as useUser  ?

So you can do below in any component ?

```
 const { userObject } = useToken() // or useUser;
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';

 + const userObject =  null; // Added this line // assuming you will need 
  only one user object in your application

  export default function useToken() {


  const getToken = () => {
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
-   return userToken?.token
+   return userToken;


  };

   const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

+  useEffect(() => {
+   if(token && !userObject){
+      setUserObject(jwt_decode(token));
+    }
+  },[token]);


  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', userToken.token);
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  

   return {
     setToken: saveToken,
     token,
+    userObject, // Added this line

   }
 }
```

In your Layout component

```
const Layout = () => {
   { userObject } = useToken();


   // don't use any hooks above this line 
   if(!userObject) return null;//will render nothing until user object is 
    available. you can also return some loader.

  //use user object after this

}
```

Comment: With the second approach, how can I get the token in a component? When I try to get it it says that userObject  is "null".

Comment: You basically need to wait until user object is available. I updated my answer with more details for the usage. Feel free to let me know if you have any questions

Comment: userObject is still null when trying to include it into the component "Layout.js". It is set as null at "useToken.js" at "userObject: token ? jwt_decode(token) : null".

Comment: I updated my answer as after knowing that token is async.  could you try now ? if it is still not working then. I may need some head space to execute my self or you try to find out your self

Comment: It gives error at the line "setUserObject(jwt_decode(userObject));". I guess because userObject here is null.

Comment: The approach works basically a few changes may needed. I will try to edit the answer by doing executing the code my self. but for now feel free to edit the answer if you find the mistake in my code.

Comment: it is my mistake in place of userObject there should be token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248880/discussion-between-sagar-and-europa).